# Choosing a smooth function with desirable properties

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Consider a smooth function $\varphi \in C^\infty[0, 1]$, where $\varphi (1) = 0$. My question is, can we necessarily choose another function $\psi \in C^\infty[0, 1]$, such that $\psi \geq 0, \psi(1) = 0$ and $\int_0^1 \psi'(x) \varphi (x) dx \leq 0$? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do we have $\varphi\ge 0$ as well?

Comment: Even if not, can't we just choose $\psi(x) = \int_x^1 \phi(y)\,\mathrm dy$?

Comment: @abiessu No, $\varphi$ is not necessarily positive.

Comment: Yes, $\psi \equiv 0$ will do.

Comment: @filmor I am not sure about this. In that case, how can we guarantee that $\psi \geq 0$?

Comment: Let $\varphi(x)=-x$. Then $\int_{0}^{1}\varphi\psi'dx = -\int_{0}^{1}\varphi'\psi dx = \int_{0}^{1}\psi \le 0$ iff $\psi \equiv 0$, since $\psi \ge 0$ is assumed. So, unless you allow $\psi \equiv 0$, then the answer is "No."

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{0}^{1}\psi'(x)\varphi(x)\,dx = \left.\psi(x)\varphi(x)\right|_{0}^{1}-\int_{0}^{1}\psi(x)\varphi'(x)\,dx = \psi(0)\varphi(0)-\int_{0}^{1}\psi(x)\varphi'(x)\,dx$$
hence it is enough to take $\psi$ in such a way that $\psi(x)$ is zero where $\varphi(x)$ is decreasing, positive when $\varphi(x)$ is increasing and big enough in absolute value. A good idea is to take $\psi=\max(0,\varphi')* g$ where $g$ is chosen in such a way that $\psi$ meets the wanted constraints, $\psi\geq 0$, $\psi\in C^{\infty}$ and $\psi(1)=0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems intuitively convincing, but it is not absolutely clear to me that such a $g$ can indeed be chosen. The smoothness part is fine. Also, it is very easy to guarantee that $\psi \geq 0$. The part about $\psi (1) = 0$ seems slightly suspect though.

Comment: @Guest: well, you may just take that $\max(0,\varphi')*g$ and re-define it over $[1-1/n,1]$ in such a way that it smoothly decays to zero, and the wanted inequality is not affected by too much (you are free to choose $n$).